# Combine list values in 1 string

Tags: python

I have list like this :

```
subsets = ["T10", "T12", "T13", "A15", "T23"]
```

I need to loop through this list checking for T followed by A and if this is found to merge T & A i.e.

This is the new list I need:

```
newset = ["T10", "T12", "T13, A15", "T23"]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the list and check for the left most value.  I just need an expression for {left char of string of next list item} - I think!

```
for i in range(len(subsets)):
  if {left char of string for next list item} = "A":
    newset.append(subset[i]+", "+ subset[i+1])
    i+=1
  else:
    newset.append(subset[i])
```

Comment: The `i+=1` in the `for` loop I'm afraid will not work. Next iteration, `i` is set again to the value given by `range` so you lost the increment. You need a `while` loop to do this.

Comment: What should happen if you have two consecutive `A` elements? E.g. `[..., "T13", "A15", "A16", "T17", ...]`? Is `A16` ignored, or is it to be combined with `T13, A15`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a new list from your items, and check if the last item in that list starts with `T`, and the current with `A`. If so, replace that last item in your new list:

```
it = iter(subsets)
result = [next(it)]
for elem in it:
    if elem[:1] == 'A' and result[-1][:1] == 'T':
        # preceding element is T.., this is A.., combine into a single string
        result[-1] = f'{result[-1]}, {elem}'
    else:
        result.append(elem)
```

I used `iter()` and `next()` to prime the output list with the first element efficiently, and save ourselves from having to test if `result` has at least one element.

Demo:

```
>>> subsets = ["T10", "T12", "T13", "A15", "T23"]
>>> it = iter(subsets)
>>> result = [next(it)]
>>> for elem in it:
...     if elem[:1] == 'A' and result[-1][:1] == 'T':
...         # preceding element is T.., this is A.., combine into a single string
...         result[-1] = f'{result[-1]}, {elem}'
...     else:
...         result.append(elem)
...
>>> result
['T10', 'T12', 'T13, A15', 'T23']
```

Note: this will also merge *consecutive* `A*` elements into a preceding `T` element, so `[..., "T13", "A15", "A16", "T17", ...]` results in `[..., "T13, A15, A16", "T17", ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `for loop` approach that returns a new list:

```
f = []
for item in subsets:
    if f and (item[:1], f[-1][:1]) == ('A', 'T'):
        f[-1] = '{}, {}'.format(f[-1], item)
    else:
        f.append(item)

print(f)

['T10', 'T12', 'T13, A15', 'T23']
```

Comment: Using `join` to combine two items is overkill; `prev + ", " + item` is much faster. `join` is more efficient when you have lots of items to combine at the same time. Here, if there were lots of strings to combine, you would just be making multiple calls to `join` instead of one single one.

Comment: Instead of `startswith` it may be simpler to just use `item[:1] == 'A' and `prev[:1] == 'T'` or even `(item[:1], prev[:1]) == ('A', 'T')`.

Comment: @chepner: and `f"{prev}, {item}"` is going to be faster still.

Comment: Next, you don't actually need `prev`. Just use `f[-1]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I forgot to time that.

Comment: Yup. `f"..."` scales much better, even for very short `prev` and `item`.

Comment: edited based on your comments, I used `format` instead of `fstrings` since I don't know which version of python3 OP might be on